# How to Hide Add an App Feature in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I am trying to hide the (add an app) feature from guest who has access to my SharePoint Online site.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the guest's site permissions to contribute, where they cannot add lists, libraries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test,you can set **Read permission level** for the guests, then he/she will not be able add apps,for more information you could refer to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels):
[image]
[image]